# Ошибка в select menu discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я пытаюсь сделать меню, в котором можно выбрать пользователя. Прочитав в документации, я нашёл UserSelect.

```
class MySelectView(View):
@discord.ui.select(cls=UserSelect, placeholder="Выберите пользователя")
async def select_callback(self, interaction, select):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Вы выбрали {select.values}")

# menu
@tree.command(name="menu", description="menu", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def menu(interaction):
    view = MySelectView
    await interaction.response.send_message("Выберите пользователя", view=view)
```

Но получаю ошибку: NameError: name 'UserSelect' is not defined 
Я не понимаю почему получаю ошибку, в документации есть пример с ChannelSelect и когда скопировал от туда код, тоже не работает.
Мои импорты:

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
from discord.utils import get
from discord import ui
from discord.ui import Button, View, Select
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ.